# Specified cast is not valid in my LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
var universitys = (from uni in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
                   orderby uni.Field<string>("universityname")
                   select new { universityid = uni.Field<Int32>("universityid"),
                                universityname=uni.Field<string>("universityname")}
                  ).ToList();
```

I have written this LINQ query in my controller, but I get the error

> Specified cast is not valid.

Nested of that I use this LINQ query

```
select uni.Field<string>("universityname")).Distinct().ToList()
```

but I want to get two fields (`universityid` and `universityname`) from dataset.

Comment: what is the type of `universityid` in the database?

Comment: Are any of the fields nullable? If so, your casts may fail when trying to convert them to non-nullable types.

Comment: Thank you Tieson T,i sloved it ya,according to your explanation i use insted of int32 ,i use int64.its working fine now.